# Smooth scrolling with framer motion and sticky table of contents

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sticky, smooth-scrolling, framer-motion

My problem:
I created SmoothScroll wrapper for my app in Next.js:

```
"use client";

import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import ResizeObserver from "resize-observer-polyfill";
import { useScroll, useTransform, useSpring, motion } from "framer-motion";

const SmoothScroll = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const scrollRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const [pageHeight, setPageHeight] = useState(0);

  const resizePageHeight = useCallback((entries: ResizeObserverEntry[]) => {
    for (let entry of entries) {
      setPageHeight(entry.contentRect.height);
    }
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => resizePageHeight(entries));
    scrollRef && resizeObserver.observe(scrollRef.current!);
    return () => resizeObserver.disconnect();
  }, [scrollRef, resizePageHeight]);

  const { scrollY } = useScroll();
  const transform = useTransform(scrollY, [0, pageHeight], [0, -pageHeight]);
  const physics = { damping: 15, mass: 0.27, stiffness: 55 };
  const spring = useSpring(transform, physics);

  return (
    <>
      <motion.div ref={scrollRef} style={{ y: spring }} className='scroll-container'>
        {children}
      </motion.div>

      <div style={{ height: pageHeight }} />
    </>
  );
};

export default SmoothScroll;
```

but, when I need to make sticky element on the page - it's not working. This element just scrolling with whole page content as if it has position:static set. Same behavior with position:fixed

Can I get help with this problem?

Sticky element is not only one child of the parent.